# Query running in phpmyadmin but not in codeigniter model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am running the following query :

```
SELECT @newNo := MAX( category_code ) FROM category_master;
INSERT INTO category_master VALUES (@newNo +1,  'Test')
```

The query runs flawlessly in phpmyadmin but it shows a database error when run using codeigniter :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO category_master VALUES(@newNo+1, 'Test')' at line 2

what could be the reason ?? 
In codeigniter model i use the following code :

```
$query = 'SELECT @newNo := MAX(category_code) FROM category_master;
                    INSERT INTO category_master VALUES(@newNo+1, 
                    \''.$category_name.'\')';
$result = $this -> db -> query($query);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot run two queries at once. Seperate them:

```
$query = 'SELECT @newNo := MAX(category_code) FROM category_master';
$result = $this->db->query($query);

$query = 'INSERT INTO category_master VALUES(@newNo+1, \''.$category_name.'\')';
$result = $this->db->query($query);
```

EDIT:
On your second query it is recommended to use query bindings:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO category_master VALUES(@newNo+1, ?)';
$result = $this->db->query($query, $category_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the query does not contains any special characters. The browser will convert the special characters, so the query is running in phpmyadmin.
To know the special characters, echo the query and copy it and paste in an editor like dreamweaver, it will show you the special characters. Hope this helps.